# Updating ARP for tap interface

Tags: network-programming, ethernet, mac-address, tap, arp

Below is the setup I have,

```
              MC#1 (eth0) <-> MC #2 (eth1)
```

With this setup, I have created a TAP interface in MC#1 and tried to ping the IP assigned to TAP interface from MC#2. When I checked the tcpdump the destination mac address is shown as the eth0 interface of MC#1 and not the MAC of the TAP interface. Also when I checked the ARP entries in the MC#2, I am able to see the MAC address of eth0 (MC#1) against the TAP interface IP.

Please explain why this happens and can we make some changes in the kernel so that the MAC address of the TAP interface to be used.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me by answering the above question? I need to know why the ARP entry is not updated for the actual tap interfaces HW and also let me know by any chance can we overcome that.

Answer (score 0):

I learned (using openvpn server) that when you ping from server (network that you want to connect to) side from host to local computer's ip, in short ARP entry is updated on local machine and it is reachable (after several tries). pinging from local computer to others not always help and might take some time. It is probably some bug with updating windows APR tables in TAP interface.